# Fundamental theorem of calculus - Application

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How do I find the derivative of the following function using the fundamental theorem of calculus? I have never seen both variable x and t within the function so I am not sure if I am right or not.

$$
F(x) = \int^x_{1} \sqrt{\cos{(x^2 +t)}} dt
$$

Is the following right?

$$
F'(x) = (2x+1)\sqrt{\cos{(x^2 +x)}} - (2x)\sqrt{\cos{(x^2 +1)}}
$$

Comment: sorry, I missed that, should be w.r.t. t

Comment: You want $F'(t)$ instead of $F'(x)$?

Comment: should be F'(x)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you haven't made any typos with the $t$ and $x$'s, the derivative cannot be computed directly using the fundamental theorem of calculus. It also requires the Leibniz integral rule, which says that (under certain regularity conditions) if we define
\begin{align}
F(x) &= \int_{\alpha(x)}^{\beta(x)}f(x,t) \, dt
\end{align}
then the derivative is calculated as
\begin{align}
F'(x) &= f(x,\beta(x)) \cdot \beta'(x) - f\left(x, \alpha(x) \right) \cdot \alpha'(x) + \int_{\alpha(x)}^{\beta(x)} \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,t) \, dt \tag{$\ddot{\smile}$}
\end{align}

In your particular example, $\alpha(x) = 1$ is a constant, $\beta(x) = x$, and $f(x,t) = \sqrt{\cos(x^2 + t)}$. So, $\alpha'(x) = 0$, $\beta'(x) = 1$, and 
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,t) &= \dfrac{1}{2 \sqrt{\cos(x^2+t)}} \cdot \left(-\sin(x^2 + t) \right) \cdot (2x) \\
&= - \dfrac{x \sin(x^2 + t)}{\sqrt{\cos(x^2 + t)}}
\end{align}

So, if you plug all of this back into  $(\ddot{\smile})$, then we find that
\begin{align}
F'(x) &= \sqrt{\cos(x^2 + x)} \cdot 1 - 0 + \int_1^x - \dfrac{x \sin(x^2 + t)}{\sqrt{\cos(x^2 + t)}} \, dt \\
&= \sqrt{\cos(x^2 + x)} - \int_1^x \dfrac{x \sin(x^2 + t)}{\sqrt{\cos(x^2 + t)}} \, dt.
\end{align}

Comment: Are you sure about that? I was told that FTC should do the work. But my answer doesn't seem right

Comment: @soulless that's because your answer isn't right. The reason the FTC doesn't apply directly is because the thing inside the integral directly depends on $x$. If instead you had something like $F(x) = \displaystyle \int_1^x \sqrt{\cos(t^2 + t)} \, dt$, then the FTC can be directly applied and you would get $F'(x) = \sqrt{\cos(x^2 + x)}$.